# ElasticSearch - How to Retrieve Count of Filtered Records > 7 days Ago

Tags: elasticsearch

I have events/records stored in ElasticSearch.  They correspond to IIS logs.  One of the fields is "logtime" which is a string field with format YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss (for example 2015-02-24 02:46:23).  Another field is "response" which is an integer field with format XXX (for example 404).  From the ElasticSearch documentation, I have been trying to construct a query through the HTTP API (mostly using Fiddler) to retrieve a count of all events such that the response code is greater than or equal to 300 for the past 7 days.  Here is a sample query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": { "match_all": {} },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "response": {
            "gte": 300
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try to slap in something like

```
"last_7_days": {
  "filter": {
    "range": {
      "logtime": {
        "gte": "now-7d",
        "lte": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

but it errors out with no message.  Any help would be appreciated.  Also, I'm not interested in the records themselves, just the counts.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you've named your filter "last_7_days", filters do not have names, only aggregations have names.  Here is the query to combine your two filters and only return the count:

```
GET index1/type1/_count
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "logtime": {
                  "gte": "now-7d",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "response": {
                  "gte": 300
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but got back no data.  I even changed "gte" to a specific date string (and removed "lte")but then got back data both before and after the date string I specified.

Comment: I think that you have a problem with your query syntax then because this works great for me.  Try to capture the input and output with Fiddler.